# Recognize and parse fregmented packet with libpcap

Tags: c, linux, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I sniffed with `libpcap` and got lot of  fragmented packet like this picture

[image: picture]

Is there any simple way to recognize fragmented packet (while I read this packet with `pcap_next_ex` and defragment this packet with C code?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any simple way to recognize fragmented packet

That depends on how you define "simple".

You will need to parse the link-layer header to determine whether the packet is an IPv4 packet or not.  If it *is* an IPv4 packet, you will need to parse [the IPv4 header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1) to see if either 1) the "More Fragments" bit is set in the "Flags" field or 2) the "Fragment Offset" field is non-zero.  If either of those are true, it's an IPv4 fragment.

> and defragment this packet with C code?

You will need a table indexed by IPv4 source and destination addresses and "Identification" field value.

For each fragmented IPv4 packet, look in that table to see if you find an entry with the same IPv4 source and destination addresses, and same Identification field value, as the ones in the fragmented packet's header.

If you don't find it, add an entry to the table, and save the contents of the packet in that entry.  If the Fragment Offset value is 0, save the entire IPv4 header, as well as the packet payload, along with its Fragment Offset value, payload length, and More Fragments flag (yes, that's redundant, as you have the full header, but you *did* ask for a simple way :-)); otherwise, just save the payload, along with its Fragment Offset value, payload length and More Fragments flag.

If you *do* find it, then, if the Fragment Offset value is 0, add the IPv4 header to the entry.  Then, regardless of the Fragment Offset value, add the packet payload, with its Fragment Offset value, payload length, and More Fragments flag, to the saved packet payload information.  This means that the entry has an IPv4 header and a *set* of packet payload/Fragment Offset value/payload length/More Fragments flag combinations.

For each fragment you add, after you've added it, check to see whether:

- if you sort the fragments by their Fragment Offset value, for all but the last fragment, the Fragment Offset value plus the payload length of that fragment is equal to the Fragment Offset value of the next fragment;
- the last fragment does *not* have the More Fragments flag set.

If that's true, you have all the fragments, and can reassemble them into an IPv4 packet whose header is the saved header from the first fragment (the one with a Fragment Offset value of 0) and whose payload is the concatenation of the payloads of all the fragments.

(Again, you asked for "simple", so I'm not discussing error handling, such as overlapping fragments, multiple fragments with More Fragments not set, etc..)